# can i use interface in logical model?

Tags: uml, diagram, class-diagram, diagramming

I am drawing Logical and physical Class diagram. in this diagram I have a class that implement interface.in physical diagram,there isn't interface,because this class,has all attribute of the base class interface.
physical diagram and logical diagram is correct?

Answer (score 0):

**First let's make our terminology clear:**

> There is nothig like "Logical and Physical Class diagram".

Logical and Physical Labels are used generally for database design.

But if you mean:

by **Logical**: Conceptual or Domain Model which show **non software objects-entities**.

by **Physical**: Class diagram which shows **real software classes** their interfaces and associtaions.

**Then**

Conceptul classes gives you **inspiration** for real software classes.And **Conceptual-Domain Classes diagrams** and  **Class Diagrams(real software classes)** should not have to be same.

> You can use abstract classes, even interface in Conceptual-Domain
>   diagram to model problem space

This does not mean there will be or should be "interfaces" in class diagram(real software classes) also. But it can be. It is your choice  how to implement solution.

> There is no rule such that Conceptual-Domain Class diagrams elements
>   should have one to one  map to Software Class Diagrams elements